# Best way to call many web services?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have 30 sub companies and every one has implemented their web service (with different technologies).

I need to implement a web service to aggregate them, for example, all the sub company web services have a web method with name `GetUserPoint(int nationalCode)` and I need to implement my web service that will call all of them and collect all of the responses (for example sum of points).

This is my base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{ // all same attributes and methods
  public long GetPoint(int nationalCode);
}
```

For each of sub companies web services, I implement a class that inherits this base class and define its own `GetPoint` method.

```
public class Company1
{
  //implement own GetPoint method (call a web service).
}
```

to

```
public class CompanyN
{
  //implement own GetPoint method (call a web service).
}
```

so, this is my web method:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public long MyCollector(string nationalCode)
        {

           BaseClass[] Clients = new BaseClass[]  { new Company1(),//... ,new Company1()}

           long Result = 0;
           foreach (var item in Clients)
           {
                long ResultTemp = item.GetPoint(nationalCode);
                Result += ResultTemp;
           }
       return Result;
       }
```

OK, it works but it's so slow, because every sub companys web service is hosted on different servers (on the internet).

I can use parallel programing like this:(is this called parallel programing!?)

```
    foreach (var item in Clients)
    {
                    Tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                        Result.AddRange(item.GetPoint(MasterLogId, mobileNumber));                  
                    }
      }
```

I think parallel programing (and threading) isn't good for this solution, because my solution is IO bound (not CPU intensive)!

Call every external web service is so slow, am i right? Many thread that are pending to get response!

I think async programming is the best way but I am new to async programming and parallel programing.

What is the best way? (parallel.foreach - async TAP - async APM - async EAP -threading)

Please write for me an example.

Comment: You got all your basics right. That's a pretty good start. `Parallel.ForEach` and `Thread`s suffer from the same problem as `Task.Run` - they are good for CPU, not IO-bound work. TAP is definitely the easiest to compose (you basically keep your current loop, but the IO stuff becomes "threadless" and very scalable). APM and EAP are easily convertible to TAP (via `Task.Factory.FromAsync` for APM and `TaskCompletionSource<T>` for EAP), so you can go with TAP and plug in APM and EAP calls if that's what your existing APIs provide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's refreshing to see someone who has done their homework.

First things first, as of .NET 4 (and this is still very much the case today) TAP is the preferred technology for async workflow in .NET. Tasks are easily composable, and for you to parallelise your web service calls is a breeze if they provide true `Task<T>`-returning APIs. For now you have "faked" it with `Task.Run`, and for the time being this may very well suffice for your purposes. Sure, your thread pool threads will spend a lot of time blocking, but if the server load isn't very high you could very well get away with it even if it's not the ideal thing to do.

*You just need to fix a potential race condition in your code (more on that towards the end).*

If you want to follow the best practices though, you go with true TAP. If your APIs provide `Task`-returning methods out of the box, that's easy. If not, it's not game over as APM and EAP can easily be converted to TAP. MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx

I'll also include some conversion examples here.

**APM** (taken from another SO question):

`MessageQueue` does not provide a `ReceiveAsync` method, but we can get it to play ball via `Task.Factory.FromAsync`:

```
public static Task<Message> ReceiveAsync(this MessageQueue messageQueue)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(messageQueue.BeginReceive(), messageQueue.EndPeek);
}

...

Message message = await messageQueue.ReceiveAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

If your web service proxies have `BeginXXX`/`EndXXX` methods, this is the way to go.

**EAP**

Assume you have an old web service proxy derived from `SoapHttpClientProtocol`, with only event-based async methods. You can convert them to TAP as follows:

```
public Task<long> GetPointAsyncTask(this PointWebService webService, int nationalCode)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<long> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<long>();

    webService.GetPointAsyncCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            tcs.SetCanceled();
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            tcs.SetException(e.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
        }
    };

    webService.GetPointAsync(nationalCode);

    return tcs.Task;
}

...

using (PointWebService service = new PointWebService())
{
    long point = await service.GetPointAsyncTask(123).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

**Avoiding races when aggregating results**

With regards to aggregating parallel results, your TAP loop code is *almost* right, but you need to avoid mutating shared state inside your `Task` bodies as they will likely execute in parallel. Shared state being `Result` in your case - which is some kind of collection. If this collection is not thread-safe (i.e. if it's a simple `List<long>`), then you have a race condition and you may get exceptions and/or dropped results on `Add` (*I'm assuming `AddRange` in your code was a typo, but if not - the above still applies*).

A simple async-friendly rewrite that fixes your race would look like this:

```
List<Task<long>> tasks = new List<Task<long>>();

foreach (BaseClass item in Clients) {
    tasks.Add(item.GetPointAsync(MasterLogId, mobileNumber));                  
}

long[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

If you decide to be lazy and stick with the `Task.Run` solution for now, the corrected version will look like this:

```
List<Task<long>> tasks = new List<Task<long>>();

foreach (BaseClass item in Clients)
{
    Task<long> dodgyThreadPoolTask = Task.Run(
        () => item.GetPoint(MasterLogId, mobileNumber)
    );

    tasks.Add(dodgyThreadPoolTask);                  
}

long[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an async version of the GetPoint:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{ // all same attributes and methods
    public abstract long GetPoint(int nationalCode);

    public async Task<long> GetPointAsync(int nationalCode)
    {
         return await GetPoint(nationalCode);
    }
}
```

Then, collect the tasks for each client call. After that, execute all tasks using [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766(v=vs.110).aspx). This will execute them all in parallell. Also, as pointed out by Kirill, you can await the results of each task:

```
var tasks = Clients.Select(x => x.GetPointAsync(nationalCode));
long[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

If you do not want to make the aggregating method async, you can collect the results by calling .Result instead of awaiting, like so:

```
long[] results = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;
```

Comment: What I meant was `var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` - sorry, should've been clearer.