# Using AsyncController to help increase concurrency on a legacy ASP.NET MVC 3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynccontroller

We have a website that is struggling with concurrent users right now.

Here is the very high-level background of the project:

- Legacy ASP.NET MVC 3 project (.NET 4)
- Can't do any major rewriting of core code
- Main entry point that takes the longest time to execute is the `SubmitSearch` action on the `Search` controller.  Average time to respond is 5-10 seconds.

So as the second point outlines, we don't want to spend too much time on this project rewriting large sections.  However, we want to attempt to increase concurrent users.  We're not looking to change anything else or increase performance since it would require much more work.

What we are seeing is that as more people hit `SubmitSearch`, the web site in general slows down.  That's most likely due to all the IIS threads being locked up executing the search.

We are looking to implement `AsyncController` and making the `SubmitSearch` action execute on a normal CLR thread.  Here's how we wanted to implement it:

Assume this is the original `SubmitSearch` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Submits a search for execution.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="searchData">The search data</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public virtual ActionResult SubmitSearch(SearchFormModel searchData)
{
    //our search code
}
```

The quickest way we were hoping to convert to `AsyncController` is to simply do this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Submits a search for execution.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="searchData">The search data</param>
/// <returns></returns>
protected virtual ActionResult SubmitSearch(SearchFormModel searchData)
{
    //our search code
}

/// <summary>
/// Asynchronous Search entry point
/// </summary>
/// <param name="searchData"></param>
public void SubmitSearchAsync(SearchFormModel searchData)
{
    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ActionResult result = SubmitSearch(searchData);
        AsyncManager.Parameters["result"] = result;
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    });

    return;
}

/// <summary>
/// Called when the asynchronous search has completed
/// </summary>
/// <param name="result"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public ActionResult SubmitSearchCompleted(ActionResult result)
{
    //Just return the action result
    return result;
}
```

Of course this didn't work because all through-out the code, we are referencing `HttpContext.Current`, which we know ends up being `null` in this approach.

So we were then hoping to do this with `SubmitSearchAsync`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Asynchronous Search entry point
/// </summary>
/// <param name="searchData"></param>
public void SubmitSearchAsync(SearchFormModel searchData)
{
    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ActionResult result = null;
        AsyncManager.Sync(() =>
        {
            result = SubmitSearch(searchData);
        });

        AsyncManager.Parameters["result"] = result;
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    });

    return;
}
```

This fixes the issue.

So here's my concern:
Does wrapping the execution of `SubmitSearch` in the `AsyncManager.Sync` method defeat the purpose of using this model?  In other words, when we are within the `AsyncManager.Sync` method, are we back on the IIS threads, which puts us back at square one?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does wrapping the execution of `SubmitSearch` in the `AsyncManager.Sync` method defeat the purpose of using this model? In other words, when we are within the `AsyncManager.Sync` method, are we back on the IIS threads, which puts us back at square one?

More or less, yes. But unfortunately, in your case, using `Task.Factory.StartNew` **also** defeats the purpose of using an async controller. With the approach you're trying to use, you can't win.

IIS threads, threads started by `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, and `Task` threads, are all taken from the *same* thread pool.

In order to gain any benefit from async controllers, you need true async methods. In other words, methods like [Stream.ReadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813.aspx) or [WebRequest.GetResponseAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync(v=vs.110).aspx). These specially-named methods use I/O completion ports instead of normal threads, which use hardware interrupts and operate on a different thread pool.

I wrote about this a long time ago in my answer here: [Using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem in ASP.NET in a high traffic scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642789/38360). Tasks and awaiters are pretty sweet, but they don't change the fundamental dynamics of the .NET thread pool.

One thing to note is that there is an option, [TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx), that you can specify when creating a `Task`, which essentially informs the framework that the task will be doing a lot of waiting, and in theory the TPL will attempt to avoid scheduling it in the thread pool. In practice, this probably won't be very practical on a high-traffic site because:

1. The framework doesn't actually *guarantee* that it won't use the thread pool. That's an implementation detail, and the option is simply a *hint* that you provide.
2. Even if it does avoid the pool, it still needs to use a thread, which is essentially like using `new Thread` - if not literally then at least effectively so. What this means is heavy context-switching, which absolutely kills performance and is the main reason why thread pools exist in the first place.

A "search" command clearly implies some kind of I/O, which means there's *probably* a real asynchronous method you can use somewhere, even if it's the old-style `BeginXyz`/`EndXyz`. There are no shortcuts here, no quick fixes; you'll have to re-architect your code to actually **be** asynchronous.

The .NET framework can't inspect what's going on inside your `Task` and magically convert it into an interrupt. It simply cannot make use of an I/O completion port unless you refer directly to the specific methods that are aware of them.

Next web or middleware application you work on, try to consider this ahead of time and avoid synchronous I/O like the plague.

Comment: Thanks for the background and info.  It basically confirmed my suspicion.  Looks like we're going to have to suck it up for now.

Answer (score 2):

I think @Aaronaught has the best answer so far: you need *true* asynchronous processing in order to scale (i.e., `Begin`/`End`, not just using thread pool threads), and that there are no shortcuts or quick fixes to asynchronous code - it will take a re-architecting of at least that portion.

Which brings me to this part of your question:

> we don't want to spend too much time on this project rewriting large sections.

The best bang for your buck is probably to purchase more memory and stick that in the server. (You should check with a profiler first just to make sure it *is* a memory issue - memory *usually* is the limiting factor on ASP.NET but it's best to check first).

As much as we developers love to solve problems, the truth is we can burn a lot of hours, e.g., changing synchronous code to asynchronous. FYI, the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (`async`/`await`) in .NET 4.5 will allow you to change synchronous code to asynchronous *much* more easily.

So for now I say buy a couple RAM chips and make a mental note to do the (much easier) upgrade to `async` after you change to .NET 4.5.

Comment: Awaiters do make it very easy to write asynchronous code in a synchronous style, but that doesn't *necessarily* make it easy to convert an entire app. The trouble is that you can't just make one little part of your application asynchronous; it basically has to be asynchronous from end to end: async controllers talking to async services talking to async repositories talking to async file I/O or database drivers, etc. It's definitely easier than it used to be, but I don't have high hopes for an app that apparently relies heavily on `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: It's not *trivial* to convert synchronous to TAP, but it is far, *far* easier than converting synchronous to any other asynchronous pattern.

Comment: (Incidentally, when *searches* are slow it generally implies an I/O rather than memory issue to me; if the search is based on some kind of database, then scaling up to more servers or indexes may be the only infrastructure solution.) But good answer nevertheless, a lot of developers overlook the infrastructure solution which can be a lot cheaper than hundreds of dev hours.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the performance of the server itself and then consider using  the profiling tools in visual studio to identify exactly what and where the bottleneck is. Consider looking at the mini profiler a discussion of which can be found here http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek9ASPNETMiniProfilerFromStackExchangeRocksYourWorld.aspx. Generally agree with the comment above about thread consumption.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of reasons that can cause the server to slow down. If we only talk about threads, threads consume a minimum of 1/4 memory each, that means the more threads drawn up from the thread pool, the more memory is consumed. This can be one of the problems causing the server to slow down.

If the response from server takes over 10 seconds, consider using Asynchronous. Like in your code, make SubmitSearchAsync function Asynchronously, it will avoid blocking a thread, and also releases the thread back to thread pool. However, like the code you provided, when a request is received from the SubmitSearchAsync action, a thread is drawn from the thread pool to executed its body.

The SubmitSearch is a synchronous action, it waits until the implementation is finished, and it blocks the thread until the implementation finishes.
In other word, you released one thread, but you also blocked another thread. If you need to synchronize code from an asynchronous thread, use the AsyncManager.Sync method. But in your case, AsyncManager.Sync might not help much. I suggest two possible solutions:

1) manually spawning a thread:

```
public virtual ActionResult SubmitSearch(SearchFormModel searchData){
    new Thread(() => { 
        //your search code
    }).Start();
}
```

In this case, your search code might take longer, but the execution of the search will be done on a thread not a part of the pool.

2) change the SubmitSearch function asynchronously along with using Parallelism:

```
protected virtual async Task<ActionResult> SubmitSearch(SearchFormModel searchData){
   // Make your search code using Parallel task like below.
  var task1 = DoingTask1Async(searchData);
  var task2 = DoingTask2Async(searchData)  
  await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2);
}
```

Aside from above suggestion, consider using Cancellation tokens, it further reduces thread usage.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> What we are seeing is that as more people hit SubmitSearch, the web site in general slows down. That's most likely due to all the IIS threads being locked up executing the search.

If it was the threads locked up then it wouldn't be a slow down but probably http errors were returned. Can I ask how many parallel hits causes the slow down? The threadpool in .Net4 is quite big. Also, if your search takes 10 seconds that means your database is doing the heavy-lifting. I would have a look at the DB performance: if other parts of your site are also DB dependent then several parallel DB intensive searches will slow down your application.

If for some reason you can't/don't want to perfmon the database then here is a simple test: change the database search call to a sleep call for X seconds (around 10 in this case). Then run your parallel requests and see if the site responsiveness drops or not. Your request thread numbers are the same so if that was the reason then it should have the same effect.